# In Perforce, how to get the highest changlist number that is the part of a label?

Tags: perforce

So, I came [this answer](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3429) on Perforce's website which seems to suggest **p4 changes -m1 @label1** as the command to use. Unfortunately, I run into ***Request too large (over 100000)*** issues with this for some labels, which is driving me absolutely crazy, because I have included the ***-m1*** option while running the command. Is there a way to avoid this error, or is there an alternative command for getting the same result. Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Can't you limit it by using a path? `p4 changes -m1 //some/path/...@label1`?

Comment: @sferencik I tried paths from the label view, but some depots throw the same error. To go further in recursively would be too much of a hassle because my script is quiet generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a label can contain an arbitrary set of revisions, the only way for the server to find the highest changelist across all of them is to scan every revision to find the changelist associated with each and return the highest one it finds, so it's O(n) where n is the label size.  If you're hitting a MaxScanRows limit at 100k, I'd assume these are labels that contain in excess of 100k files?  You can see how many records are scanned by any given command by running it with the `-Zdbstat` flag, like this:

```
p4 -Zdbstat changes -m1 @label
```

Increasing MaxScanRows is one solution, as P4Jen said, but it won't make the command scan any fewer rows or consume any less time.  As a more holistic solution I would suggest getting away from manually populated labels if possible, and moving to labels that are defined as simple changelist aliases:

```
Label: label
Revision: @CHANGE
View:
```

Note that to get the full performance benefits of an "alias" label (i.e. a label treated exactly the same as a change) the Revision field must be set to a changelist and the View field must be empty (if the View field isn't empty you get an "automatic" label which has its own performance peculiarities).

With an alias label, you can get the equivalent changelist by just looking at the label as an O(1) operation.  :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are hitting the 'MaxScanRows' limit.

This would have been set by an admin.

More info about it is here:
  http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2529

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) But I know that. I wanted to know if there's a way to avoid it, or if there's an alternate command to accomplish the same. Regards.